# I want grid view to be displayed as a whole

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I have a layout which has a scroll view and includes another layout which has a grid view. The problem is when I change the screen orientation the root layout(which has scroll view) isn't scrolling but the grid view inside the child layout is implementing a scroll view and it's items are not displayed on a whole. I want the root layout to always scroll and grid view to always show all it's items, without any scroll. How to do this??

Internal layout XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/loginCardRadius"
android:elevation="5dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginViewsMargin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/loginViewsMargin"
android:background="#ffffff">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/loginViewsMargin">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/string1"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginViewsMargin"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:numColumns="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

External Layout XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:weightSum="12"
            android:background="@drawable/login_shape_bk"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_login_bk" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/research_work"/>

            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_advisors"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `GridView` with `RecyclerView`

I am trying with this and work perfectly

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                                    app:spanCount="2"/>
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions. This conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218611/discussion-between-dinesh-and-aashish-chandra). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to incorporate all relevant information.

Comment: Dinesh brother, I tried the answer which you referred to but once an item is selected, and we try to select some other item, the previous item is also being highlighted. I want to highlight one item at a time, and then a loading spinner should appear and fragment switch should take  place. Basically when one item is selected user should be unable to select other item, something like that....